# How can I save the first link in google search automated by selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I have a task that involves searching city names/states for their government website. I've written the following code that selects the "I'm feeling lucky" search option to open the first search result, and append the URL to the list. This works, until I get a location that uses ".org" instead of ".gov," and i get a "NoSuchElementException" with the "I'm feeling lucky" search function.

```
newlist= []
loop = 0
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path)
while loop<1001:
    for item in city_state:
        driver.get("https://google.com/")
        search = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        search.send_keys(item)
        time.sleep(5)
        button = driver.find_element_by_name("btnI")
        button.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        url = [driver.current_url]
        newlist = newlist+url
        loop= loop+1
```

How can I either (1) implement a custom exception for NoSuchElementException, where if raised, appends " " instead of the search result OR (2) click the first search result in the google search (which i will screen for inaccurate links manually later)?

Comment: Which call is raising the NoSuchElementException?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to handle the exception, you could try out something like:

```
for item in city_state:
    try:
        driver.get("https://google.com/")
        search = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        search.send_keys(item)
        time.sleep(5)
        button = driver.find_element_by_name("btnI")
        button.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        url = [driver.current_url]
        newlist = newlist + url
    except NoSuchElementException:
        # Now you can either append nothing to the list
        # (or any message/character that you want)
        newlist = newlist + ["(your message)"]
        # Or you can implement your code 
        # that clicks on the first search result
        # (Don't know much about Selenium so I'll leave this
        # to you/other people answering)
```

Please correct me if you've found any mistakes or a better way to do this, and I hope you get to solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

It's good that you know why your code is giving exception. That's the main thing that keeps everyone's headbanging.

So once you have done that, the next thing is to catch this exception. For this, a simple try-catch block will work.

Now the next thing you need to do is write code for part, after the exception is caught.

Try something like this:

```
newlist= []
loop = 0
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path)
while loop<1001:
    for item in city_state:
        
        # Not adding these parts in the try catch block
        # because these can throw exception realted to some other cause
        # you can write another try catch for this
        # or nest them as per your choice
        driver.get("https://google.com/")
        search = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        search.send_keys(item)
        time.sleep(5)
        
        # try catch block
        try:
            button = driver.find_element_by_name("btnI")
            button.click()
            time.sleep(5)
            url = [driver.current_url]
            newlist = newlist + url
            loop= loop+1
        except NoSuchElementException:

            # Opting choice 1 to append " " in list
            newlist = newlist + [" "]
```